# if something is 2^(N+1), how can i get N back from the end result?

Tags: math

I'm working on a GIF encoder in C# as a spin-off to something else GIF related i was working on.

In the GIF spec there is a "Logical Screen Descriptor" in the header of the file, one of these being how large the global colour table is.

From what i understand the Global Colour Table is anywhere from `0-256`, stored as 3 bits in the format 2<sup>(N+1)</sup>, where N is the decimal value between 1 and 7.

I'm creating a function where i can specify the table size as an integer between 0-256 and then perform a calculation on this to find `N`.

For example, 2<sup>(7+1)</sup> = 256, how can I get back to 7 from 256?

Ive spent over an hour with a pencil and a sheet of paper trying to remember how to "balance equations" from my time in college but i cant seem to remember...

Comment: Your question is really about maths, and is therefore ff topic on this site; go to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I was going to but i cant find a tag on there that applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), specifically the [base 2, or *binary* logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm). Wikipedia says:

> It is the inverse function of the power of two function. The binary logarithm of n is the power to which the number 2 must be raised to obtain the value n. That is:
>   [image]

In C#, you can compute it using [`Math.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd50b6h5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is finding if a = 2<sup>n+1</sup> then n = log<sub>2</sub>(a) - 1. here is the java code :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int n = 256;
    double log = Math.log(n)/Math.log(2);
    System.out.println(log-1);
}
```

Online [version](http://ideone.com/QsGPMK)